# zoom set to 4 but on get zoom shows zero ,OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, zoom

```
var map1 = new OpenLayers.Map('firstmap');
var wms1;
var state1="<%=state%>";
var cql_filter1="st_nm='"+state1+ "'";
wms1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
       "http://localhost:8083/geoserver/wms", {layers: 'india:india', 
       'CQL_Filter': cql_filter1,center: [22.2587, 71.1924],
        zoom: 4
        } );

map1.addLayer(wms1);
map1.zoomToMaxExtent();
console.log(map1.getZoom());
```

The output of map1.getZoom() is 0 and map is also not zoomed so how should I set zoom?

Answer (score 3):

The default `maxExtent` of a map with a default projection is the world.  `center` and `zoom` can be set as map options or by centering the map:

```
var map1 = new OpenLayers.Map('firstmap');
var wms1;
var state1="<%=state%>";
var cql_filter1="st_nm='"+state1+ "'";
wms1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
       "http://localhost:8083/geoserver/wms", {
          layers: 'india:india', 
          'CQL_Filter': cql_filter1
        } );

map1.addLayer(wms1);
map1.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(22.2587, 71.1924).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'), map.getProjectionObject()
  ), 4);
console.log(map1.getZoom());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked

Answer (score 1):

`Zoom` is not a valid WMS parameter so will be ignored by the server. Also once you call `map1.zoomToMaxExtent();` you will get whatever zoom level matches the full extent of your map (possibly that of the WMS layer).